# Applying the mean value theorem for multivariate functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

In the Salas Calculus book (page 805 in the 10th edition) they say that $g(t) = f(\mathbf{a} + t[\mathbf{b} - \mathbf{a}]), t \in [0,1]$. I get that the point is to find an equivalent single variable function and use the MVT to solve the problem. How do you form a single variable function in this case?

For example, if the original function is $f(x,y) = x^3 - xy$, I have two points $\mathbf{a} = (0,1)$ and $\mathbf{b} = (1,3)$, and I'm asked to find a point $\mathbf{c}$ on the line segment formed by points $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ such that $f(\mathbf{b}) - f(\mathbf{a}) = \nabla f(\mathbf{c}) \cdot (\mathbf{b} - \mathbf{a})$. A similar question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441564/mean-value-theorem-application-for-multivariable-functions), but it doesn't seem to work in the case where the my two points have different x,y, and z values.

Comment: Your question makes no sense: $f$ is a function on $\mathbb{R}^2$, but $\mathbf{a}\in\mathbb{R}^3$, so $f(\mathbf{a})$ is not defined.

Comment: Good catch! Sorry, I fat fingered the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is straightforward: just do the algebra.

Note $\nabla f=\langle3x^2-y,-x\rangle$, so, with $\mathbf{c}=\langle c_1,c_2\rangle$, we have $$\nabla f(\mathbf{c})=\langle 3c_1^2-c_2,-c_1\rangle$$
But $\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{a}=\langle1,2\rangle$, so $$\nabla f(\mathbf{c})\cdot(\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{a})=3c_1^2-c_2-2c_1$$
You want this to equal $f(\mathbf{b})-f(\mathbf{a})=-2$ subject to the constraint that $$\mathbf{c}=\mathbf{a}+t(\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{a})=\langle0,1\rangle+t\langle1,2\rangle=\langle t,2t+1\rangle$$ for some $t\in[0,1]$. So set $c_1:=t$ and $c_2:=2t+1$ and substitute into the equation $$3c_1^2-c_2-2c_1=-2$$
Then solve for $t$.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!